# Illustrator Opacity Mask Not Fully Hiding Object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, transparency, mask

I'm trying to make a logo and I'm having trouble cutting out part of a line. I'm trying to use an opacity mask to do this because using the pathfinder tool changes how the lines look. The problem I'm having is for some reason my mask is not fully hiding the line.

[image: semi-transparent line inside triangle should not be visible at all]

(semi-transparent line through middle should not be visible)

I have checked to see if opacity or color were the problem and they don't appear to be.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a version of 100K black color which has an rgb representation of about 32,32,32 something like that. What you do is go into your opacity mask and if you are using CMYK or RGB, doesn't matter, you make it RGB and ensure the R,G and B values are all 0. Even if you are doing CMYK, the all-zero rgb values in your opacity mask will not affect your printing except provide the expected 100% opacity like you desire.