# Creating a linear gradient line wavy effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm new to illustrator and graphic design, and attempting to learn my way around gradients by recreating some designs. I'm trying to replicate this effect like the one in the image below, and I feel like I've gotten 80% of the way there, but it feels as though something is missing. For example I understand how to create the fading effect from top to bottom, but how can you achieve the opacity on the sides? Also, in the second object, there's a second color inside the gradient that I've found impossible to replicate. Looking for some insight, and thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any "second color" you elude to. I think it's just a visual anomaly due to the line spacing and surrounding elements (perhaps some artifacts in the jpg.)

I also don't think there are any gradients on the lines. I think they are merely a solid color fill and an **opacity mask** is actually doing all the "fading".

---

## Opacity Mask

The short answer....

A detailed explanation can be found in Illustrator's help files here: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-opacity-masks-transparency.html

---

The longer, perhaps more specific, answer...

Create a shape on top of your artwork which encompasses what you *want* to be visible. Fill that shape with the `Registration` swatch.

> **Important Note** because this shape will be a *mask*, using the `Registration` swatch is preferred so the shape will mask *all* colors 100%. Normally one would *never* use the `Registration` swatch for any *artwork* to be reproduced. Simply put, `Registration` **only** because if usage as described here, otherwise **never** use the `Registration` swatch. Using the `Black` swatch, although it *looks* the same, can fail to hide 100% of all colors on a *mask*.

Create "soft" edges on that top shape. *how* you create soft edges is up to you. It can be done with gradients, gradient meshes, an embedded raster image, or a filter. The shape needs to "blend" between the `Registration` color and either white **or** transparency.

Select the art and the top shape and on the **Transparency Panel** click `Make Mask`. 
Tick `Invert Mask` if necessary, and/or untick `Clip` if necessary.

The top shape *should* now be a **mask** on the base artwork.

Visual representation which may be easier to follow....

[image]

---

What often throws users off here is further editing. The **Transparency Panel** has 2 little thumbnail images on it... you *must* click the mask thumbnail to edit the *actual* mask shape or object. Then you *must* click the art thumbnail on the panel to edit *anything* which is *not* the mask.

Above, I clicked the mask thumbnail, then increased the Feather amount. Then I clicked the artwork thumbnail to continue drawing *anything* else.

If you fail to click the artwork thumbnail, and continue drawing *other*, even unrelated, objects, those new object will be part of the *mask* (and often not directly visible which can really confuse users).

---

Using things like a **Gradient Mesh** for the mask shape will offer **much** more control than simple effects, such as `Feather`, offer.

[image]

---

And using **raster** images will work as well...

[image]

Be aware though, raster images are *raster* and will be bound by all the traditional restraints raster images come with. Using a raster image on a mask doesn't change its nature. Its no different than using a raster image in the artwork - scaling/distorting rasters in Illustrator, even if they are on an Opacity mask, *can* lead to "broken pixels".

---

Like all masks, 100% black (or Registration) will *hide* portions of the artwork and 100% white will *show* portions of the artwork. Ticking the `Invert Mask` option on the Transparency Panel reverses these.

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for the step by step tutorial. Out of curiosity, if I wanted to go on and print the artwork made using this technique, will using  the registration swatch cause issues down the line? I know printing is a whole other beast, but given your disclaimer in the beginning, I was wondering if you had experience there.

Comment: Hi @Kmo -- Because the Registration swatch is *only* used for the **mask** it's *doesn't* actually print at all. Only what's *visible* on the artboard actually gets printed. This technique is *absolutely fine* for print work. I do it all the time. You're wise to be aware of using the Registration swatch. That's why I've included warnings in the answer. Registration is fine for a **mask** but *never* okay in actual artwork.

Comment: You *can* test the difference by merely using the `Black` swatch. Often what you'll see is very slight colors still showing through the mask. Sort of detailed here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131911/issue-with-obtaining-full-transparency-around-design-when-making-tiff-files/131939#131939 here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64083/why-doesnt-my-opacity-mask-fully-hide-my-object and here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117691/illustrator-opacity-mask-not-fully-hiding-object

Comment: Scott,- As an aside, could I ask you about the viability of using gradients (like the one in the image and the one you showed me how to make) in printing? I've heard that gradients are difficult to get right, especially for packaging printing.

Comment: @Kmo it really depends upon the colors, the gradient span, the gradient steps, the reproduction method, etc. There's no *inherent* issue with gradients. But long gradients with only minute color changes can create "banding" (where you see actual steps in the gradient). There's not a lot one can do in *illustrator* about banding other than reducing the length of the gradient. In Photoshop, one can add dithering or noise to help reduce banding.

Comment: Scott, re-reading my question, I forgot that it's not technically a gradient, so hopefully it won't be an issue in the future. Thank you so much for taking the time to share your expertise with me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help `:)` Once you play with Opacity Masks a few times, you'll quickly pick up on how they work.